# Set "component state" by hand in GenerateTableFetch processor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, apache-nifi

I use "component state" in the GenerateTableFetch processor to make sure to not query the same data twice from a database. Due to a migration, the flow had to be deployed again, losing its state during the process. How can I set the "component state" of this processor by hand? I tried using the ExecuteScript processor (using ECMAScript) standalone, to update the state. At first I tried to read the state with

```
var Scope = Java.type('org.apache.nifi.components.state.Scope');
var map = context.stateManager.getState(Scope.LOCAL).toMap();
```

But I don't get a loopable map back. What I don't understand is how I select the GenerateTableFetch processor to set the state.

Answer (score 2):

The StateManager only gives a component access to modify it's own state, not the state of another component, otherwise any component could incorrectly alter another components state.

Behind the scenes the state is stored using the UUID of the component. If you are in a cluster then it is stored in ZooKeeper and you may be able to manually modify the data in ZooKeeper using the ZK CLI. If you are in standalone then it is stored in a write-ahead-log in state/local and I'm not sure there is a good way to manually modify that.

Also, when migrating the flow to a new cluster the preferred mechanism is to use the ZK state migrator from nifi toolkit:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#zookeeper_migrator

If you were migrating between standalone instances then just copy state/local from original cluster to new cluster.

Comment: How do you copy the state? I can't modify it by hand.

Comment: @pfnuesel this may help https://docs.cloudera.com/cfm/2.0.1/hdf-migration/topics/cfm-migrate-state-and-components.html